# How to execute variable array of object-specific functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, prototype

Though I have experience in javascript and read articles about how to handle objects, it still confuses me sometimes as I am used to the classical object oriented behavior. So I want to share my current problem:

I want the PIXI-Sprite Object (that has properties position.x, .y and speedX , SpeedX) to have a method called "move", that changes the position according to the speed.

```
PIXI.Sprite.prototype.move=function()
{
    this.position.x += this.speedX;
    this.position.y += this.speedY;
};

var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(picture);
sprite.position.x=0;
sprite.position.y=0;
sprite.speedX=1;
sprite.speedY=1;
```

When I call the method for "sprite" every frame this works fine:

```
sprite.move();
```

Now I want to have an array of functions that can be chosen individually for each sprite. So all of the functions in the array are executed every frame. So I created an array with this function:

```
sprite.ai=[];
sprite.ai.push(sprite.move);
```

When I now execute this function...

```
sprite.ai[0]();
```

...an error is thrown:

TypeError: this.position is undefined

Can you tell me why this is. I think that this is because "this" is now the array and not the sprite, but I don't know how to get the sprite object. How would be the proper way to achieve what I want?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a `bind` method on `Function`s that returns a new function with `this` fixed to whatever you specify:

```
sprite.ai.push(sprite.move.bind(sprite));
```

Alternatively, you can pass a function expression that makes a direct call to `sprite.move()` in turn:

```
sprite.ai.push(function () {
    sprite.move();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. This works. However -- as I'm having multiple sprites -- there is not just one Sprite object "sprite", but an array of Sprite objects "sprites". So the sprite that is created is added to that array:

```
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(tShot);

sprite.x=hero.x;
sprite.y=hero.y;
sprite.speedX =  0;
sprite.speedY = -1;

sprite.ai[0]=(function(){sprite.move()});

sprites.push(sprite);
container.addChild(sprite);
```

Then I call every frame:

```
sprites[i].ai[0]();
```

But now only one object is moved -- the last one that was created. The more objects exist, the faster this single object moves. So i concluded, that though every object has the function "move", it is always bound to the same object and therefore this object is moved.

When I call

```
sprites[i].move();
```

ever frame, it works how it should. Can you tell me why this is. This would help me a lot to understand the behavior of javascript.